# MySQL Client taking more than 14 sec to be connected

Tags: mysql, connectivity, network

IN our on-prem server we have installed mysql 4 node cluster 2 for mgmt and 2 for datanode. All are physical server with 1TB ram and 64 core processor. When a user trying to connect to mysql server from application VM its taking more than 14 second. But in my case while connection to that server from my computer its taking less than a second. For application VMs we provide we give them a IP range. IS ip range are the problem ? Because after connection being established its taking less than a second to fetch or get response from db server. But for each new connection its taking 14 second and this issue is while connecting from application VM. Is it a problem in networking or MySQL server ? Because while I ping db server from that server the avrg is 1.3 ms.

From My Computer

┌──(basu㉿basu)-[~]

└─$ time mysqlshow -h xx.xx.xx.xx -u test1 -pTest@123 test1

Database: test1

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| real | 0.06s |
| user | 0.03s |
| sys | 0.00s |
| cpu | 65% |

------------------- FROM VMWARE -------------

[centos@Test-AC01 ~]$ time mysqlshow -h xx.xx.xx.xx -u test1 -pTest@123 test1
mysqlshow: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.

Database: test1

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| real | 0m16.526s |
| user | 0m0.007s |
| sys | 0m0.006s |

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I t seems to be network+config related to me. Usually the skip-name-resolve due to a bad dns config cause this issue.

Comment: Yes currently I'm not facing the issue. It was a network related problem.